# How to list all surveys using a web service?

Tags: web-services, list

I am trying to use the Lists.asmx service to gain access to surveys on a Sharepoint server.

I would like to be able to list all of the surveys without showing all the other kinds of lists there.

The idea is to select a survey by name (not GUID) and to then evaluate the responses. I am hoping that the web service will provide information about the questions too - multi-choice, rating range, data type etc.

Can anyone help here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `SiteData.asmx` service's function `GetListCollection` to give you all the lists in the site.

From there you can filter by `BaseType == "Survey"` to get all the surveys.

For the next part you will need to use `Lists.asmx` service's function `GetList` to give you an XML representation of the list.

It returns the `schema.xml` of the list (CAML), so you'll need to parse that. This should be enough to get you started.